# Debian Bullseye Compatible Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, debian, raspbian-lite, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am working on the Raspbian Buster OS.

To move from Buster to Bullseye, I have to make the following changes.

1. Updating source list.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Replace any occurences of `buster` with `bullseye`.
2. Update packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
   ```

I would like to know when will the Debian Bullseye compatible Raspberry Pi OS be expected to be released?

Answer (score 2):

No one can answer your question - it is unanswerable, just as the question, "When will the universe collapse on itself?" You've asked for an *opinion*, not an answer. That said, it seems likely that the `bullseye` release will happen before the universe collapses.

With respect to the *"in-place upgrade"* you've referred to, it may be a good learning experience, but unlikely to turn out as well as you'd wish. Raspberry Pi OS has **never** provided a sanctioned/guaranteed *"in-place upgrade"*, and it seems highly unlikely they will start now.

If I were determined to try a `bullseye` upgrade in advance of the official release, as an *"in-place upgrade"*, I would [read RonR's post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=317888), and try his upgrade script. Why? He has something quite rare: ***credibility***.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest very soon:

"*Software seems to be the name of the game in 2021. For starters, Raspberry Pi is aiming to migrate the platform to Debian 11 by the middle of the year.*"
I found it on [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/raspberry-pi-after-launching-five-devices-in-less-than-a-year-heres-what-theyre-doing-next/) webside. Personally I also tried to upgrade it with the sources.list, but it did not work well, e.g. the sound is strange.